# Spring batch mongo item reader doesn't not restart

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-batch

How does mongo item reader refreshes/recreates page request between jobs? 
From code as I've seen - the only way to refresh page requests is to set read.count in step execution context. On start of job read count in step execution context is 0 or empty so page request won't refresh

Answer (score 0):

I suppose [`AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.saveState`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.html#setSaveState-boolean-) property should solve your problem